# Is there a switch statement-type selection control mechanism in HyperTalk?

Tags: hypercard, hypertalk

In the 1996 reference manual [HyperCard Script Language Guide: The HyperTalk Language](https://cancel.fm/stuff/share/HyperCard_Script_Language_Guide_1.pdf), there is a section about nested `if` structures, but there doesn't seem to be anything about `switch`-like statements. Is there a `switch` statement-type selection control mechanism in HyperTalk? And if not, is there a good workaround, beside creating a very large nested `if` structure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native switch (or case) statement syntax.

If you want to identify your selected case by an integer, you can just put all the possible choices into a single variable as an array, then refer to e.g. `item [number] of [variable]`

Answer (score 1):

HyperCard does not have a switch/case construct. If you want to do lots of conditional queries, you have to do nested if/then/else like

```
if marriedStatus = "Married" then
    GetMarriedInfo
else if marriedStatus = "Single" then
    GetSingleInfo
else
    GetNeitherInfo
end if
```

(This is a chain of multi-line `if` statements with single-line `else` statements containing another multi-line `if`)

If you just want to look up values that are indexed by a number, you can use HyperTalk's support for text items to put your values into a text field or variable, then look up those using chunk syntax:

```
put 2 into theNumber -- number that needs to be mapped to a choice
set the itemDelimiter to "|" -- default is comma
put "Jeanne|Sioux|Jacqueline" into choices
put item theNumber of choices into foundChoice
```

You can also use this together with the `do` command to call different handlers, like in:

```
do "Get" & marriedStatus & "Info"
```

which will take whatever the `marriedStatus` variable contains (e.g. `"Single"`) and then builds the text `"GetSingleInfo"` from it, and then has do call that, which calls the command handler of that name in the current handler. But note that this only works if you have a fixed set of values in marriedStatus, because otherwise your script will abort because `"GetI don't careInfo"` is not a valid command handler name (not to mention you never defined a handler of that name in your script).

For what it's worth, SuperCard added a switch statement (and most HyperCard clones inherited that):

```
switch marriedStatus
    case "Married"
        GetMarriedInfo
        exit switch
    case "Single"
        GetSingleInfo
        exit switch
    case true -- default case
        GetNeitherInfo
        exit switch
end switch
```

You can have more complex expressions in a case, basically it just compares the switched value with the case value.